# How to invoke an action on keyUp in Ember text field

Tags: ember.js

Just starting out with Ember, I wanted to perform some action when a user types something in a text field. I first tried this

```
<input type="text" {{bind-attr value=qty}} {{action "checkQty" on="keyUp"}}/>
```

That correctly initialized the text field's value and called the `checkQty()` function in my controller's `actions` hash, but I was not getting the updated value for `qty`. So it seems `bind-attr` is a one-way deal.

I tried using the `TextField` view:

```
{{view Ember.TextField value=qty onEvent="keyPress" action="checkQty"}}
```

I had to use `keyPress` instead of `keyUp` because [onEvent only allows enter or keyPress](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.TextField.html#property_onEvent). This worked, except that reading qty's value on `keyPress` gives me the value of the field before the user pressed the key and not afterward.

So I wound up using the input helper to specify the field:

```
{{input type="text" value=qty}}
```

And created an observer in my controller:

```
checkQty: function() {
  Ember.Logger.log('qty: ', this.get('qty'));
}.observes('qty').on('change')
```

So that works, but now I am confused about best practices for architecting my Ember app. It *seems* like the prescribed method is for your template to effectively call actions on your controller. My usage of an observer feels like a hack to get around my failure to get this working in a template.

After looking at the Ember source code, I was able to extend `TextField` to get the behavior I wanted:

```
MyApp.TextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
  keyUp: function(event) {
    this.sendAction('action', this.value);
  }
});
```

And my template then became:

```
{{view MyApp.TextField value=qty onEvent="keyUp" action="checkQty"}}
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this in Ember?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to utilize the sendAction method, here is an example

```
# coffeescript code sample
window.App = Ember.Application.create()

# define the keyupaction callback on all TextField views
Em.TextField.reopen
  keyUp: (e) ->
    @sendAction('keyUpAction', e)

# the keyup callback specific for each controller
App.ApplicationController = Em.Controller.extend
  actions:
    foobar: ->
      console.log 'do yor validation here'

# the text field view
{{view Em.TextField valueBinding="firstName" keyUpAction="foobar"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be accomplished within the route of a template, or better yet, within a component using key-up="actionname".

Handling the data of the input field (and any others associated with it) within a component will utilize Ember's defaults instead of adding new logic and simply allow for handling the data returned.

```
//.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    checkQty(q) {
      console.log(q);
    }
  }
});

//.hbs
{{input type="text" key-up="checkQty"}}
```

You could take it a step further if you need to edit the qty on the input within your action by binding it to a property.

```
// .js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  qty: 0,
  actions: {
    checkQty(q) {
      console.log(this.get(qty));
    }
  }
});

// .hbs
{{input type="text" value=qty key-up="checkQty"}}
```